# CMake compile to static .lib file

Tags: cmake

I'm struggling to get Cmake to compile a C++ project into a static .lib file so I can then link it another project. Here's my basic setup:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT (MyProj)

IF (NOT ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION} LESS 3.1)
    cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 OLD)
ENDIF ()

set(SRCS_COMMON
#Here I locate the relative paths to a bunch of .cpp files
#../../Source/Common/Math/Example.cpp
)

ADD_LIBRARY(MyProj_static STATIC ${SRCS_COMMON})
TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(MyProj_static PRIVATE ../../Include)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(MyProj_static PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME MyProj_static)
```

When I run CMake, I don't necessarily want to create a *.vcxproj file for my project.  Rather, I simply want it to compile this project into a .lib file so it can be linked to another target.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

CMake isn't a standalone build tool, so you can't build your code with just it. You can generate NMake makefiles or Ninja if you want to do without `.vcxproj`.

In the latter case make sure you run CMake from within "Visual Studio Developer Prompt".